# Who (which) was the mathematician "Abel" who countered Cauchy's "proof?"

Tags: calculus, math-history

...as in this quotation:
"Cauchy's approach to rigour didn't save him from errors, however. He 'proved' incorrectly that the limit of a convergent series of continuous functions is continuous. Abel produced a counterexample."

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide the source of the quote? There is a very famous Abel from that time, but there were other not-so-famous Abels too.

Comment: It is the great mathematician (Neils Henrik) Abel.

Comment: @UmbertoP., http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Extras/Cauchy_Calculus.html.

Comment: There is an extensive discussion of this affair in I. Lakatos “Cauchy and the Continuum: the significance of non-standard analysis for the history of mathematics" (1980).  (Niels Henrik) Abel famously remarked (in an 1826 paper on the binomial theorem) that “it seems to me that [Cauchy's] theorem admits exceptions” and it is a matter of some debate exactly what he meant by this.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably [Niels Henrik Abel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Henrik_Abel).

[Wikipedia on uniform_convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#History) says:

> In 1821 Augustin Louis Cauchy published a proof that a convergent sum of continuous functions is always continuous, to which Niels Henrik Abel in 1826 found purported counterexamples in the context of Fourier series, arguing that Cauchy's proof had to be incorrect.

Unfortunately, Wikipedia does not contain a reference to a publication by Abel on this.

Comment: Thatnk you,   Doc

Comment: Niels Henrik Abel fits exactly.  Thank you,   Doc

Comment: The Abel paper is “Unterschungen über die Reihe: $1 + \frac ma x + \frac{m(m-1)}{1\cdot 2}x^2\cdots$”, *Journal für reine und angewandte Mathematik* **1826**, 1 (1826) pp.311–339.